# Вывод Wordpress цикла записей с дополнительными элементами

Tags: php, wordpress

Как включить в WordPress цикл записей блога вывод дополнительных элементов? Я создал шаблон записи для опеределенной рубрики, где есть thumbnail, title, excerpt и дополнительно в шаблон включил элемент с текстовым контентом, который будет там генерироваться автоматически, допустим это элеметы div с классом .custom. Далее я создал на странице записей цикл, который будет выводить все записи из этой определенной рубрики, я могу вывести thumbnail, title, excerpt, но не знаю как вывести в этом цикле .custom . Как правильно построить цикл, чтобы мой .custom так же подтягивался из шаблона записи? Спасибо

```
<?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
          query_posts('cat=1');   
          while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
        ?>
        <div class = "programs-flex-item">
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__image"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
          <div class = "programs-flex-item__excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
          <div class = "custom">ЗДЕСЬ ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЙ КОНТЕНТ</div>

        </div>
         <?php 
          endwhile; 
          endif;
        wp_reset_query();                
      ?>
```

Comment: Дополнительные элементы - это поля, добавленные через Advanced Custom Fields?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin нет, это будет сумма чисел, которые будут генерироваться js и будет для каждой записи своя. Как ACF сделать я знаю

Comment: Генерироваться скриптом в этом же файле я надеюсь? И как генерироваться - после цикла и отрисовки шаблона или при каждой итерации цилка?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin  в шаблоне будут выведены числа, а скрипт будет их суммировать, ну и после отрисовки шаблона, но а как это может повлиять?

Comment: Влияет на понимание вопроса в целом.

Comment: Во первых срочно гуглить почему не нужно использовать `query_posts`. Во вторых напиши в вопросе что такое ` .custom` который "нужно вывести"

Comment: .custom это неважно какой контент, просто кусок html который я хочу передать в цикле. Будет такой див с классом или айди custom (например), и он будет пустой сам по себе, html в него загонит js

Comment: Ну и в чем вопрос? Вы уже вывели div class="custom", Перепишите его контент с помощью js, и все.

Comment: Ну если "не важно", то вопрос вообще не имеет смысла.

Comment: @SeVlad какая разница какой контент? хтмл контент. Я уже не первый раз вижу ваши несомненно полезные советы, но можете сюда не писать больше